# Android Linear Layout steching

Tags: android

I think that's a rather simple Question but I don't get it the way I want it to.
I Want do do a Linear Layout in Android with 3 areas.

The Top area should have a fixed height, fill_parent width.
The second, below the first, should use all the room available, fill_parent width.
The third, below the second, should have fixed height, fill_parent width.

Here is what i got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:background="#ff63a920">
   <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/top_bar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="32dp"
>
</LinearLayout>
  <com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mymapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"


        />
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/bottombar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="32dp"
>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Problem is, that the mapview in the middle ist too big, so it pushes out the topbar.

I Hope you can help me.

Comment: I wonder if making the top-level container a RelativeLayout would be a better idea.

Comment: Have you tried `layout_weight` settings?

Comment: I said it was simple: layout_weight=0 for top and Bottom and =1 for the mapview did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sebastian that's what made the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:background="#ff63a920">
   <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/top_bar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="32dp"
android:layout_weight="0"
>
</LinearLayout>
  <com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mymapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/bottombar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="32dp"
android:layout_weight="0"
>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a software called DroidDraw. (freeware) use it and it will generate the XML code autmatically for u.

Hope that helps